# Use Chartjs with reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js

I want to use ReadtFauxDom with chartJS, but the chartJS doesn't render anything(FauxDom is empty), I think this pb is due to the fact that ReactFauxDOM.element('canvas').getContext('2d') doesn't existe
[image]
What do you think ? (if that true, how can i create a dom and use it to generates my charts)

here the code:

```
var Chart = require('chart.js');
class BarReact extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super()
    }
    componentWillMount() {
        var ctx = new ReactFauxDOM.Element('canvas');

        var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {

            type: 'bar',
            data: {
                labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
                datasets: [{
                    label: '# of Votes',
                    data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
                    backgroundColor: [
                        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
                    ],
                    borderColor: [
                        'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
                    ],
                    borderWidth: 1
                }]
            },
            options: {
                scales: {
                    yAxes: [{
                        ticks: {
                            beginAtZero: true
                        }
                    }]
                }
            }
        });
        this.setState({ chart: ctx })
    }

    render() {

        return (

                        {this.state.chart.toReact()}

        )
    }
}
```

NB: I'm using
"chart.js": "^2.5.0",
"react-faux-dom": "^3.0.1"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is helpful (not used react-faux-dom) but I do the following; render a canvas element using react then when the component mounts use that moment to create the graph

```
import React from 'react';
import Chart from 'chart.js';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class ChartComponent extends React.Component {


    componentDidMount() {
        this.initializeChart(this.props.config);
    }

    initializeChart(options) {
        let el = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.chart);
        let ctx = el.getContext("2d");
        let chart = new Chart(ctx, options);
    }

    render() {
        return (<canvas ref="chart" height="400px" />);
    }

}

export default ChartComponent;
```

Answer (score 2):

Also You can use `React.createRef()` from React16

```
class Chart extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.chartRef = React.createRef();
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const ctx = this.chartRef.current.getContext('2d');
    new ChartJS(ctx, options); // eslint-disable-line no-new
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <canvas ref={this.chartRef} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I think this is the right answer and I've upvoted but I use new Chart(this.chartRef.current, options) - I don't know what ChartJS is and I've not needed .getContext('2d'). This helped me because I forgot .current so thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import Chart from "chart.js";
​
​
class GraphChart extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.myRef = React.createRef();
​
      }
​
      componentDidMount() {
        const ctx = this.ctx;

        new Chart(ctx, {
          type: "bar",
          data: {
            labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow"],
            datasets: [
              {
                label: "# of Likes",
                data: [12, 19, 3],
                backgroundColor: [
                  "rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)",
                  "rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)",
                  "rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)"
                ]
              },
              {
                label: "# of Likes",
                data: [-12, -19, -3],
                backgroundColor: [
                  "rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)",
                  "rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)",
                  "rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)"
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        });
      }

      render() {

        return (
            <div>
                <canvas width='800' height='300' ref={ctx => (this.ctx = ctx)}/>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default GraphChart;
```